# JAVA element.getElementsByTagName Restrict to Top Level

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have an XML file as follows:

```
<rootNode>
    <link>http://rootlink/</link>
    <image>
        <link>http://imagelink/</link>
        <title>This is the title</title>
    </image>
</rootNode>
```

The XML Java code using DOM is as follows:

```
NodeList rootNodeList = element.getElementsByTagName("link");
```

This will give me all of the "link" elements including the top level and the one inside the "image" node.

Is there a way to just get the "link" tags for rootNode within one level and not two such as is the case for the image link?  That is, I just want the http://rootlink/ "link".

Answer (score 13):

You could use [XPath](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPath.html):

```
XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = xpathFactory.newXPath();
NodeList links = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("rootNode/link", element,
    XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

Answer (score 11):

I couldn't find any methods to do that either so I wrote this helper function,

```
 public static List<Element> getChildrenByTagName(Element parent, String name) {
    List<Element> nodeList = new ArrayList<Element>();
    for (Node child = parent.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling()) {
      if (child.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE && 
          name.equals(child.getNodeName())) {
        nodeList.add((Element) child);
      }
    }

    return nodeList;
  }
```

Comment: The if loop is always true. i tried like this... 

for (int nodeCnt = 0; nodeCnt < nl.getLength(); nodeCnt++) 
{
if (nl.item(nodeCnt).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE &&  tagName.equals(nl.item(nodeCnt).getNodeName())) {
}
}

Here nl is the nodelist containing the all the elements(including child )

Comment: I landed here looking for a way to do this in Javascript. This answer helped me. I started with this code and turned it into JS.

`function getChildrenByTagName(parent, name) {
    var nodeList = [];
    for (var child = parent.firstChild; child != null; child = child.nextSibling) {
 
      if (child.nodeType == 1 && name == child.nodeName) {
        nodeList.push(child);
      }
    }

    return nodeList;
  }`

Comment: PHP: function getChildrenByTagName($parent, $name){
    $nodeList = array();
    foreach($parent->getElementsByTagName($name) as $child){
        if($child->nodeType == 1){
            array_push($nodeList, $child);
        }
    }
    return $nodeList;
}

Answer (score 3):

If you can use [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/) instead, you can do this:

```
element.getChildren("link");
```

With standard Dom the closest you can get is to iterate the child nodes list (by calling getChildNodes() and checking each item(i) of the NodeList, picking out the nodes with the matching name.

Comment: I thought about JDOM, but I've written a lot of code with DOM.  I have to look at the level of effort to convert.  But is there no way to do it with DOM?

Comment: I don't think there is a convenient way to do it. but you can create a method that gets calls getChildNodes(), checks each item's name, adds the items to a new NodeList, then returns the NodeList. Use that method wherever you need to get the named children. Or bite the bullet and use JDom, I find it a lot easier to deal with.

Comment: Thank you.  I will look into the different solutions suggested.  Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but nonetheless I have an alternative solution to add.

It's not the most efficient, but works:

Get all the children using getElementsByTagName, then just check each one has the same parent to the one you started with.

I use this because I have a set of results, each result can have results nested inside it. When I call my Result constructor I need to add any nested results, but as they themselves will look for their own children I don't want to add children to the current level (their parent will add them).

Example:

```
NodeList children = resultNode.getElementsByTagName("result");
for(int i = 0; i<children.getLength(); i++){
   // make sure not to pick up grandchildren.
   if(children.item(i).getParentNode().isSameNode(resultNode)){
        addChildResult(new Result((Element)children.item(i)));
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this function to get the node value by tagName, restrict to top level

```
public static String getValue(Element item, String tagToGet, String parentTagName) {
    NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(tagToGet);
    Node nodeToGet = null;
    for (int i = 0; i<n.getLength(); i++) {
        if (n.item(i).getParentNode().getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase(parentTagName)) {
            nodeToGet = n.item(i);
        }
    }
    return getElementValue(nodeToGet);
}

public final static String getElementValue(Node elem) {
    Node child;
    if (elem != null) {
        if (elem.hasChildNodes()) {
            for (child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child
                    .getNextSibling()) {
                if (child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
                    return child.getNodeValue();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```